# Reaching internal chrome pages with Python webbrowser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have a program where I'm using Python's `webbrowser` module to open a browser and navigate to a page automatically. My code essentially looks like the following:

```py
import webbrowser

chrome_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
url = "stackoverflow.com"

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

When doing it with a normal site it works exactly as expected. However, when I instead substitute in an internal Chrome site of the format `chrome://<page>` (e.g. `chrome://dino` or `chrome://version`) for the url, Chrome opens as expected, but it does not navigate anywhere but rather instead stays on my new tab page.

Why are normal urls (and even strings such as "hello world") working as expected, but only chrome-specific pages not? Is there any way to get around this?

(This is on Windows 10 & Python 3.6.8 by the way).

Comment: I can't speak for `webbrowser`, but I can confirm that `Chrome('chromedriver.exe').get('chrome://dino')` works in selenium. You might want to give that a try

Comment: @DeepSpace I'll give selenium a try but I am still hoping to stick with `webbrowser` since it's a bit simpler and (I believe) already comes with Python.

Comment: try registering it? `webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
`

Comment: Yes, it is pre-installed in python. I tried your code and I got the same output.

Comment: @Ruturaj when I run your line followed by `webbrowser.get('chrome').open("stackoverflow.com")` I now instead get it returning False and not opening Chrome at all.

Comment: In Chrome, automatic navigation to `chrome://` paths is prohibited. Likely to prevent malicious interaction with browser settings.

Comment: @JamesJJ Any source to back up that claim? It certainly works on my MacBook.

Comment: @Selcuk is executing `chrome_path chrome://version` in the terminal working for you?

Comment: @DeepSpace That doesn't work (a regular URL works though).

Comment: Try: `webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path), 1) `

Comment: @Ruturaj still the same result as in my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed does not work, but it's not `webbrowser`'s fault.

A small diving into the code shows that, at the end of the day, `webbrowser` simply calls `subprocess.Popen(args)` where `args` ending up being

`'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe <url>'`.

If you simply open a terminal window and execute

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" chrome://dino`

you will get the exact same behavior: Chrome opens and stays on the home page, so the problem is lying somewhere in Chrome's code (either a bug or a design choice).

It works with `selenium` since I assume it is using some black-OS-magic (ie interprocess communication) so it does not rely on Chrome's code. It just mimics a user.

Comment: This is a good answer as to a possibility, though I'm still wondering why this is (and why not the case on Mac per @Selcuk's above comments) and how to work around this

Comment: I disagree with the first half of this (Up to the last paragraph). When I tested it, I was able find that the `:` in the `url` variable of `chrome://dino` is where webbrowser stops reading the url. Therefore, it only opens up `chrome`.

Comment: You can see that `import webbrowser

chrome_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
                      url = "chrome//dino"
                      webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)` works perfectly fine, without the `:`

Comment: @MLavrentyev As to the *why*, I don't know, ask Google. As to *how to get around this*. use a tool that allows this, ie selenium

Comment: @ArnavPoddar Does not work for me. Chrome opens up and tries to access `https://chrome//dino`

Comment: @ArnavPoddar the `:` seems to only be a problem for internal sites specifically, since opening `about:about` in the terminal for Firefox works. Also, opening `https://stackoverflow.com` also works.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. @MLavrentyev I thought the string wasn't fully reading, but it is, in fact, another issue that is probably what was stated in the above answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this, since this is the best answer and I don't see any more forthcoming.